# Is it safe to construct DateTime() from GET?

Tags: php, security, datetime

Is the following code safe?

```
$d = new DateTime($_GET["date"]);
```

AFAIK there are no direct ways to use date format string for malicious purposes. However, there may be some peculiarities in different OS, so - would you add an additional check to ensure that date look exactly like `yyyy-mm-dd`?

I'm using both PHP5.6 & PHP7.

Comment: It depends on what you're going to do with `$d` next

Comment: You should always check for the date format, but not only for security reasons (here there is not much security issue), but to "manage" your logs... you may give a better message that "unexpected string in __construct()...", in case the format is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this code is always safe.  In the worst case someone tries to send something malicious and an exception is thrown because it's not a valid date.  I would wrap it in a try/catch:

```php
try {
    $date = new \DateTime($_GET["date"]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // Log and return a status code of 404 or similar
}
```